# NameSpaceBinding and wsadmin

Tags: websphere, websphere-6.1, wsadmin, jacl

I am trying to create a StringNameSpaceBinding using the wsadmin tool of Websphere 6.1

Here are the steps i take
set cell [$AdminConfig getid /Cell:cell/]
$AdminConfig create StringNameSpaceBinding $cell { {name bindname}  {nameInNameSpace Bindings/string} {stringToBind "This is the String value that gets bound"} }

But when i run this last step i get an error like this:
WASX7015E: Exception running command: "$AdminConfig create StringNameSpaceBinding $cell { {name bindname}  {nameInNameSpace Bindings/string} {stringToBind "This is the String value that gets bound"} }"; exception information:
 com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7444E: Invalid parameter value "" for parameter "parent config id" on command "create"

Any idea what could be up with this?

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm betting that the following command:

```
set cell [$AdminConfig getid /Cell:cell/]
```

Doesn't work. Most likely, `cell` is not the name of your cell.
You don't need to specify a cell name; there's only one cell in the WAS topology. I would change this to:

```
set cell [$AdminConfig getid /Cell:/]
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar issue and it is now resolved after removing both node and cell name from the following line:

```
cell = AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:/Node:/Server:WebSphere_Portal/')
```